# PDE/Analysis graduate courses

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I'm just starting my graduate studies in Analysis and PDE's and am a bit lost about what topics should I cover in order to do a good Phd program.
I`ve already done the usual undergrad courses, plus Real and complex analysis (graduate level), functional analysis and measure theory.

So, if you guys can recommend me which courses I should do, (I can get my university to open new courses as needed), and which books I should study, it'd make me really happy

Comment: You can also have a look at this topic: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564961/good-pde-books-for-a-graduate-student/568314#568314

Comment: I'm looking more for topics/courses to cover . I have the basics down for PDE(chapters 2,3, 5,6,7)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Some interesting courses that can be done with a standard PDE course:** (with exemplary lecture notes so you can have a look into these)

- [Calculus of Variations](https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~dgomes/notas_calvar.pdf)

  1. Finite dimensional optimization problems
  2. Calculus of variations with one independent variable
  3. Calculus of variations and elliptic partial differential equations
  4. Deterministic optimal control and viscosity solutions
- [Nonlinear Evolution Equations](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/notes/nonlinev.pdf)

  1. The Contraction mapping Theorem
  2. Sobolev Spaces and Laplace’s Equation
  3. The Diffusion Equation
- [Reaction-Diffusion Equations](http://www-m6.ma.tum.de/~kuttler/script_reaktdiff.pdf)
- [Interactions between Dynamical Systems and PDEs](http://www-m8.ma.tum.de/personen/kuehn/PDF_files/main_v2.pdf)

  1. Implicit Functions and Lyapunov-Schmidt
  2. Crandall-Rabinowitz and Local Bifurcations
  3. Sturm-Liouville and Stability of Travelling Waves
  4. Exponential Dichotomies and Evans Function
- [PDEs and Mathematical Modeling](https://www.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/disertori/PDG-web-version.pdf)

  1. Continuum Mechanics
  2. Hydrodynamics
  3. Elasticity Theory
- [Semi-Group Theory](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr08.pdf)
- [Variational Methods](http://www-m6.ma.tum.de/~brokate/pde_ss16.pdf)

  1. Sobolev Spaces
  2. Homogenization
  3. Monotone Problems
  4. The Bochner Integral
- [Numerics of PDEs](https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/john/LEHRE/NUM_PDE_FUB/num_pde_fub.pdf)

  1. Finite Difference Methods
  2. Ritz-Galerkin Method
  3. Finite Element Methods
  4. Finite Volume Methods

**And some Analysis courses:**

- [Fourier Analysis](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~mohammad/teaching/Fourier/LectureNotes_A3/draft_1.pdf)

  1. Laplace Transform
  2. Fourier Series
  3. Fourier Transform
  4. Schwartz Functions
- [Distribution Theory](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~stein/lehre/SoSem09/distrvo.pdf)

  1. Distributions
  2. Tempered Distributions
  3. Distributions with compact support
- [Dynamical Systems](http://users.ntua.gr/antkar/EDUCATION/nlds.pdf)

  1. Linear Systems and Stability
  2. Nonlinear Systems and Stability
  3. Bifurcation Theory
  4. Chaos Theory
- [Differential Forms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07862.pdf)

  1. Differential Forms: Definition
  2. Hodge Star Operator
  3. Lemma of Poincare
  4. Stokes' Theorem
- [Nonlinear Functional Analysis](http://www.dim.uchile.cl/~chermosilla/Nonlinear%20Functional%20Analysis.pdf)

  1. Analysis in Banach Spaces
  2. Brouwer Mapping Degree
  3. Leray-Schauder Mapping Degree

Comment: Nice, do you have any ideas about analysis courses also? The lecture notes are really welcomed!

Comment: @DavidStolnicki I updated some analysis courses. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for posting all of these notes @Fritz. These are interesting topics for self-study.

Answer (score 5):

Graduate level course in Complex Analysis, Real Analysis and PDE's which usually cover the following textbooks:

1. Complex Analysis by Lars Ahlfors
2. Complex Analysis by Elias M. Stein & Rami Shakarchi
3. Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces by Elias M. Stein & Rami Shakarchi
4. Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications by Gerald B. Folland
5. Partial Differential Equations by Lawrence C. Evans

Then a graduate level course in Functional Analysis.

Comment: That was the book I used for functional analysis. Great book!

Comment: I've gone through most of those books,  any idea about more advanced courses?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed Point Theory is an important part of analysis to cover. And if you want to mix analysis with a little bit geometry, you MUST check the two brilliant books by I. Chavel: eigenvalues in riemannian geometry and isoperimetric inequalities. They do reveal beatiful applications of PDE's to geometric problems.